# Как сверстать fluid grid?

Tags: html, css

Есть вот такая индусская верстка. Её необходимо сверстать как на скриншоте

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```html
<center>
  <a href="http://magadanmedia.ru/news/hashtag/767/" style="position: relative;"><img alt="" height="165" src="http://www.primamedia.ru/files2/upimg/magadanmedia/mmcitypeople.jpg" style="position: relative;height: 100%;max-height: 100px;margin: 5px;" width="323"><span style="position: absolute;left: 1em;bottom: 0.1em;color:  black;font-size: 26px;"><tt style="font-family: inherit; opacity: 0.5;">#</tt> Люди</span></a>
  <a href="http://magadanmedia.ru/news/hashtag/743/" style="position: relative;"><img alt="" height="165" src="http://www.primamedia.ru/files2/upimg/magadanmedia/mmcityfood.jpg" style="position: relative; margin: 5px;" width="323"><span style="position: absolute;left: 1em;bottom: 0.1em;color:  black;font-size: 26px;"><tt style="font-family: inherit; opacity: 0.5;">#</tt> Еда</span></a>
  <a href="http://magadanmedia.ru/news/hashtag/777/" target="_blank" style="position: relative;"><img alt="" height="165" src="http://www.primamedia.ru/files2/upimg/magadanmedia/mmcityplace.jpg" style="position: relative; margin: 5px;" width="323"><span style="position: absolute;left: 1em;bottom: 0.1em;color:  black;font-size: 26px;"><tt style="font-family: inherit; opacity: 0.5;">#</tt> Места</span></a>
  <a href="http://magadanmedia.ru/news/hashtag/778/" style="position: relative;"><img alt="" height="165" src="http://www.primamedia.ru/files2/upimg/magadanmedia/mmcitytrack.jpg" style="position: relative;height: 100%;max-height: 100px;margin: 5px;" width="323"><span style="position: absolute;left: 1em;bottom: 0.1em;color:  black;font-size: 26px;"><tt style="font-family: inherit; opacity: 0.5;">#</tt> Тропы</span></a><br>
  <p>
    <a href="https://t.me/MagadanMediaChat" target="_blank"><img title="Город в Телеграм" src="/files2/upimg/magadanmedia/mmcitytg.jpg" alt="" width="800" style="width: 100%;" height=""></a>
  </p>
</center>
```

Как этого можно добиться? Еще и адаптивно для мобилок и планшетов)

P.S Без использования гридов) и желательно без классов, если это возможно)

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79270/discussion-on-question-by-----fluid-grid).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно использовать многоколончатый текст. Для этого `<center>` задай `style="display:inline-block; column-width: 323px; column-gap: 10px; column-count: 2;"`

*Смотреть в режиме "На всю страницу".*

```html
<center style="display:inline-block; column-width: 323px;
    column-gap: 10px;
    column-count: 2;">
  <a href="http://magadanmedia.ru/news/hashtag/767/" style="position: relative;"><img alt="" height="165" src="http://www.primamedia.ru/files2/upimg/magadanmedia/mmcitypeople.jpg" style="position: relative;height: 100%;max-height: 100px;margin: 5px;" width="323"><span style="position: absolute;left: 1em;bottom: 0.1em;color:  black;font-size: 26px;"><tt style="font-family: inherit; opacity: 0.5;">#</tt> Люди</span></a>
  <a href="http://magadanmedia.ru/news/hashtag/743/" style="position: relative;"><img alt="" height="165" src="http://www.primamedia.ru/files2/upimg/magadanmedia/mmcityfood.jpg" style="position: relative; margin: 5px;" width="323"><span style="position: absolute;left: 1em;bottom: 0.1em;color:  black;font-size: 26px;"><tt style="font-family: inherit; opacity: 0.5;">#</tt> Еда</span></a>
  <a href="http://magadanmedia.ru/news/hashtag/777/" target="_blank" style="position: relative;"><img alt="" height="165" src="http://www.primamedia.ru/files2/upimg/magadanmedia/mmcityplace.jpg" style="position: relative; margin: 5px;" width="323"><span style="position: absolute;left: 1em;bottom: 0.1em;color:  black;font-size: 26px;"><tt style="font-family: inherit; opacity: 0.5;">#</tt> Места</span></a>
  <a href="http://magadanmedia.ru/news/hashtag/778/" style="position: relative;"><img alt="" height="165" src="http://www.primamedia.ru/files2/upimg/magadanmedia/mmcitytrack.jpg" style="position: relative;height: 100%;max-height: 100px;margin: 5px;" width="323"><span style="position: absolute;left: 1em;bottom: 0.1em;color:  black;font-size: 26px;"><tt style="font-family: inherit; opacity: 0.5;">#</tt> Тропы</span></a><br>
  <p>
    <a href="https://t.me/MagadanMediaChat" target="_blank"><img title="Город в Телеграм" src="/files2/upimg/magadanmedia/mmcitytg.jpg" alt="" width="800" style="width: 100%;" height=""></a>
  </p>
</center>
```

Уменьшение между колоночного расстояния.

```html
<center style="display:inline-block; column-width: 323px;
    column-gap: 1px;
    column-count: 2;">
  <a href="http://magadanmedia.ru/news/hashtag/767/" style="position: relative;"><img alt="" height="165" src="http://www.primamedia.ru/files2/upimg/magadanmedia/mmcitypeople.jpg" style="position: relative;height: 100%;max-height: 100px;margin: 5px;" width="323"><span style="position: absolute;left: 1em;bottom: 0.1em;color:  black;font-size: 26px;"><tt style="font-family: inherit; opacity: 0.5;">#</tt> Люди</span></a>
  <a href="http://magadanmedia.ru/news/hashtag/743/" style="position: relative;"><img alt="" height="165" src="http://www.primamedia.ru/files2/upimg/magadanmedia/mmcityfood.jpg" style="position: relative; margin: 5px;" width="323"><span style="position: absolute;left: 1em;bottom: 0.1em;color:  black;font-size: 26px;"><tt style="font-family: inherit; opacity: 0.5;">#</tt> Еда</span></a>
  <a href="http://magadanmedia.ru/news/hashtag/777/" target="_blank" style="position: relative;"><img alt="" height="165" src="http://www.primamedia.ru/files2/upimg/magadanmedia/mmcityplace.jpg" style="position: relative; margin: 5px;" width="323"><span style="position: absolute;left: 1em;bottom: 0.1em;color:  black;font-size: 26px;"><tt style="font-family: inherit; opacity: 0.5;">#</tt> Места</span></a>
  <a href="http://magadanmedia.ru/news/hashtag/778/" style="position: relative;"><img alt="" height="165" src="http://www.primamedia.ru/files2/upimg/magadanmedia/mmcitytrack.jpg" style="position: relative;height: 100%;max-height: 100px;margin: 5px;" width="323"><span style="position: absolute;left: 1em;bottom: 0.1em;color:  black;font-size: 26px;"><tt style="font-family: inherit; opacity: 0.5;">#</tt> Тропы</span></a><br>
  <p>
    <a href="https://t.me/MagadanMediaChat" target="_blank"><img title="Город в Телеграм" src="/files2/upimg/magadanmedia/mmcitytg.jpg" alt="" width="800" style="width: 100%;" height=""></a>
  </p>
</center>
```

Comment: Отличный вариант, только не могли бы вы подсказать, я могу как то избавиться от расстояния между колонками? Уж слишком оно большое, а     column-width: 0px;
    column-gap: 0px; его практически совсем не уменьшают)

Comment: @ЕвгенийШалаев, расстояние между колонками регулируется  column-gap. Если менять в браузере с помощью панели разработчика, то эффект не виден. Нужно менять кодом.

Comment: `<center>` в 2018-м году?

Comment: @SashaOmelchenko что поделать) легаси)

Comment: @ЕвгенийШалаев А у вас в Chrome нормально отображается? У меня почему-то разметка в одну колонку отображается.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov если смотреть на весь экран то все нормально, а так да - в одну колонку)

Comment: @ЕвгенийШалаев У меня очень криво на самых разных разрешениях. То в одну, то в две, то в 4. И даже когда в две, есть немалые отступы http://prntscr.com/jxjbgg Мне тоже сама задумка нравится, но почему-то в Chrome и IE с ней проблемы. Разве что в Firefox всё хорошо. Если что, используемая ОС — Windows 10.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov у меня так же. При достаточной ширине вьюпорта оно становится как на вашем скриншоте, что бы починить нужно убрать `column-count: 2;`

Answer (score 3):

Можно для этого случая использовать flexbox, тогда придётся задать фиксированную высоту блоку и я изменил высоту для некоторых картинок убрав `height: 100%; max-height: 100px`, заменив на `height: 88px`. Также для этого, возможно, придётся поменять порядок картинок, так как они уже располагаются в столбик, а не в строчку.

```css
center {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-content: center;
  height: 290px;
  text-align: left;
}

center > * {
  flex-shrink: 0;
}
```

```html
<center>
  <a href="http://magadanmedia.ru/news/hashtag/767/" style="position: relative;"><img alt="" height="165" src="http://www.primamedia.ru/files2/upimg/magadanmedia/mmcitypeople.jpg" style="position: relative; height: 88px;margin: 5px;" width="323"><span style="position: absolute;left: 1em;bottom: 0.1em;color:  black;font-size: 26px;"><tt style="font-family: inherit; opacity: 0.5;">#</tt> Люди</span></a>
  <a href="http://magadanmedia.ru/news/hashtag/743/" style="position: relative;"><img alt="" height="165" src="http://www.primamedia.ru/files2/upimg/magadanmedia/mmcityfood.jpg" style="position: relative; margin: 5px;" width="323"><span style="position: absolute;left: 1em;bottom: 0.1em;color:  black;font-size: 26px;"><tt style="font-family: inherit; opacity: 0.5;">#</tt> Еда</span></a>
  <a href="http://magadanmedia.ru/news/hashtag/777/" target="_blank" style="position: relative;"><img alt="" height="165" src="http://www.primamedia.ru/files2/upimg/magadanmedia/mmcityplace.jpg" style="position: relative; margin: 5px;" width="323"><span style="position: absolute;left: 1em;bottom: 0.1em;color:  black;font-size: 26px;"><tt style="font-family: inherit; opacity: 0.5;">#</tt> Места</span></a>
  <a href="http://magadanmedia.ru/news/hashtag/778/" style="position: relative;"><img alt="" height="165" src="http://www.primamedia.ru/files2/upimg/magadanmedia/mmcitytrack.jpg" style="position: relative; height: 88px;margin: 5px;" width="323"><span style="position: absolute;left: 1em;bottom: 0.1em;color:  black;font-size: 26px;"><tt style="font-family: inherit; opacity: 0.5;">#</tt> Тропы</span></a><br>
  <p>
    <a href="https://t.me/MagadanMediaChat" target="_blank"><img title="Город в Телеграм" src="/files2/upimg/magadanmedia/mmcitytg.jpg" alt="" width="800" style="width: 100%;" height=""></a>
  </p>
</center>
```